# Is there a way to use scipy.optimize.minimize with 2D np array as x0?

Tags: scipy, nested-lists, solver, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am new to optimization techniques that python offers and I couldn't find a way on how to adjust optimize.minimize from scipy for my needs.

What I would like to do is to minimize the sum of square differences between the market price and the modeled price for the given set of bonds by changing the rate (so the rate would be my x0). This sum is calculated via price_eval, which takes few lists or nested lists as arguments, for instance the nested list of cash flow amounts per every bond. To make the latter more clear - if I have 3 bonds and they have 3, 2 and 4 future cash flows of some amounts like a,b,c; d,e; h;i;j;k respectively, one of the arguments would be the list CF_list = [[a,b,c],[d,e],[h;i;j;kl]].

Here's a function:

```
def price_eval(rates_list, ttm_list, price_list, CF_list, CF_time_list, N_cf_list):

    price_model_list = []
    sum_squares = 0

    for i in range(0, len(price_list)):
        
        price = 0
        number_cf_per_bond = N_cf_list[i]
        
        for j in range(0, number_cf_per_bond):
            
            price += (CF_list[i][j]) / math.pow(1+rates_list[i][j],CF_time_list[i][j])
   
        diff = price_model_list[i] - price_list[i]
        sum_squares += math.pow(diff,2)

    return sum_squares
```

I was trying to define the solver as

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(price_eval, rates_guess, args=(ttm_list, price_list, CF_list, CF_time_list, N_cf_list))
```

where I provide the nested list rates_guess as the initial guess for rates_list[i][j] for solver (it doesn't really matter if I change it to a numpy array or not, gives the same result). The whole problem probably comes from the fact that scipy.optimize.minimize only takes 1-D arrays as x0, while in my case x0 needs to be two-dimensional due to data stored per every bond per every cash flow. I get an error

```
...
grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

So, my question is whether anyone has an idea on how to tackle this? Or whether it's possible to somehow adjust solver in a way I can provide a nested list/2D np array as x0 which should be given back with new values in a same format? If not, what else can I do?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Regardless of what you provide as `rates_guess`, the `rates_list` variable provided to your function will be 1d.  You can reshape it or otherwise manipulate it to suit the calculations.  The original structure of `rates_guess` is of no significance to the `minimize` code, since it is just varies the values in response to the objective value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `rates_list` and `rates_guess` need to be 1d arrays/lists. The way I usually deal with this is by having functions that flatten your preferred structure into a list, and 'inflate' it back to the desired shape. So you can have, for example, something like this

```
def to_flat(nested_list):
    '''
    flatten a list of lists
    '''
    flat_list = []
    for l in nested_list:
        for e in l:
            flat_list.append(e)
    return flat_list

# test
rates_nested_list = [[1,1,1],[2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
rates_flat_list = to_flat(rates_nested_list)
print('flat: ',rates_flat_list)

def from_flat(flat_list, list_to_copy_shape_from):
    ''' 
    here the second argument is a nested list in the desired shape -- values not relevant only shape
    '''
    nested_list = []
    idx = 0
    for l in list_to_copy_shape_from:
        nested_list.append([])
        for e in l:
            nested_list[-1].append(flat_list[idx])
            idx += 1
    return nested_list

# test
template = [[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
rates_nested_list2 = from_flat(rates_flat_list, template)
print('nested:',rates_nested_list2)
```

check the output:

```
flat:  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
nested: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Now in your `price_eval` function you will be given, by the optimizer, a flattened rates list and you need to 'inflate' it, so your code would look like this

```
def price_eval(rates_flat_list, ttm_list, price_list, CF_list, CF_time_list, N_cf_list):

    # create a nested list of rates from a flat one, using CF_list as a template
    rates_flat_list = from_flat(rates_flat_list,CF_list)

    price_model_list = []
    sum_squares = 0

    for i in range(0, len(price_list)):
        
        price = 0
        number_cf_per_bond = N_cf_list[i]
        
        for j in range(0, number_cf_per_bond):
            
            price += (CF_list[i][j]) / math.pow(1+rates_list[i][j],CF_time_list[i][j])

        # !!! I think your code is missing the following line !!!
        price_model_list.append(price)
        diff = price_model_list[i] - price_list[i]
        sum_squares += math.pow(diff,2)

    return sum_squares
```

Now when you call the optimizer, as `x0` you need to pass a flattened list, so assuming `rates_guess` is a nested list you would call

```
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(price_eval, x0 = to_flat(rates_guess), args=(ttm_list, price_list, CF_list, CF_time_list, N_cf_list))
```

finally, when you get `res` it will have a solution as a flat list so you may want to call `from_flat` on that again

Finally, since you are doing a least squares fit anyway, you may want to use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` instead of minimize -- it has pretty much the same inputs but should be better in fitting

Comment: many thanks for your suggestions and such a clear answer! it's a very smart solution indeed that I haven't thought about. This way it does work, however the new generated rates I get from the solver do not make much sense (using least_squares only few rates end up being different from the initial guess and therefore they cause spikes in the initial curve while it should be rather smooth). One of the reasons could be perhaps the fact that I do not apply any constraints on the output, so I tried to define that - I'll post it as the next answer

Comment: @lullasky glad it was helpful! if so consider accepting the answer per the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers